# c# how to implement real-time image streaming

Tags: c#, image, real-time

I'm trying to transfer an image data from my machine to a remote machine in real-time like vpn so the image changes over time.
After trying udp, I realized that it's size limit makes that impossible.
Before I try tcp, I want to ask if there is a utility that I can use.
Someone told me that even that will not be real-time and I need to send the differences only.
Please give me some guidance.

Comment: This is called video streaming, and lots of working solutions exist for it - google for "C# video streaming"

Comment: Video streaming solutions such as LibVLC typically restrict users to using a files with specific format. I do not have a video. I'm just rendering images with opengl.

Answer (score 0):

UDP size limit is not the issue or constraint here. TCP or UDP both will have a packet data size limit (configurable) and requires tweaks to receive and send buffer to elongate those limits to some extent.

In your case that changing image data is to be sent and used in real time so as @EugenRieck suggest go for video streaming options and you will be able to achieve what you intend to, based on the problem description provided.

Video are basically rendering of frames (images) per second.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in wikipedia, "The practical limit for the data length which is imposed by the underlying IPv4 protocol is 65,507 bytes" for UDP;

so I tried TCP instead and it works perfectly fine.
The rendering speed over different countries is acceptable as realtime eventhough I have no compression algorithm.
Any ideas to improve it are relavant and welcome.